# Can not find runtime target for framework .NETCoreApp=v1 compatible with one of the target runtimes

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to migrate an Asp.Net Core RC1 project to RC2 and have been following this [documentation](http://dotnet.github.io/docs/core-concepts/dnx-migration.html) and have also followed the [instructions](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/migration/rc1-to-rc2.html) for DNX migration to .NET CLI.

I am getting the following error when I try `dotnet run`:

> Can not find runtime target for framework '.NETCoreAPP, Version=v1.0'
>   compatible with one of the target runtimes: 'win10-x64, win81-x64,
>   win8-x64, win7-x64'. Possible causes:
>
> 1. The project has not been restored or restore failed -run 'dotnet restore'
> 2. The project does not list one of 'win10-x64, win81-x64, win7-x64' in the 'runtimes'

I have run `dotnet restore` and it seems to have completed successfully.

I have updated all the relevant packages to RC2.

Answer (score 290, accepted):

I should have done exactly what the error message said. When migrating from RC1, I did not realise that I had to specify a `runtimes` section in my `project.json` file.

In my `project.json` I added the following section:

```
"runtimes": {
    "win10-x64": { }
  }
```

And I was good to go.

---

**Update 27 February 2017**

New project templates in Visual Studio 2017 RC no longer require run times to be specified (in `project.json` or `.csproj`) in advance if you choose to deploy your app as a `Framework Dependent Deployment` (FDD).

If, however, you choose to deploy your app using `Self-contained Deployment` (SCD), then you will need to specify all the run times you want your app to run on *in advance* in your `.csproj` file.

Below is an example of a `.csproj` file for an app that uses the SCD deployment method:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp1.0</TargetFramework>
    <VersionPrefix>1.0.0</VersionPrefix>
    <DebugType>Portable</DebugType>
    <RuntimeIdentifiers>win10-x64;osx.10.11-x64</RuntimeIdentifiers>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="9.0.1" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Please see [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/preview3/deploying/index) for more information, which includes a thorough description of both types of deployment options, as well as their benefits and disadvantages.

Comment: I created a new project in VS 2015 Update 3. And still had this section missing.

Comment: I think it is not always necessary to add this setting. The documentation says: "If you are a portable class library that can run on any runtime, you don't need to specify a runtime." - That's true for most of my projects, but this error appeared when I added an Entity Framework Core project to my solution. I think EF Core - at least in its RC2 state - has a limitation on which platforms it can run on, thus, projects that reference it, might need to comply with those settings. But I'm only guessing. Documentation is really confusing at this point.

Comment: Agreed, documentation around this issue in particular remains scarce. I have a feeling you are correct regarding Entity Framework Core.

Comment: Didnt even need this on a new 1.0 Core VS2015 template, updated to 1.0.1 and got the above error, thx for the fix!

Comment: @SteveMcNiven-Scott - Same here. I also had to add another line in "runtimes" to get it to restore and build on Ubuntu Server: "ubuntu.16.04-x64". YMMV but the error should point out the platform you're missing and would need to add.

Comment: The error message does not mention "project.json". How people are supposed to guess??

Comment: This solution might work fine on an MVC project, but my old ASP.NET WebForm project does not have a **project.json** file.

Comment: Actually, I had to combine both this answer and @Mike_G answer [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39534983/2324602) to get my solution to work. See also [link](http://www.jamessturtevant.com/posts/ASPNET-Core-cannot-find-runtime-for-framework-dotnetcoreapp/)

Comment: Agreed @usefulBee, no idea how developers are supposed to magically know to modify project.json.

Comment: In my case, I had to add "win8-x64" and "win81-x64": to the runtimes and then do a "dotnet restore" and then the "dotnet run app.dll" worked.

Comment: Working out of VS2015, I also had to run dotnet restore, with win10-x64 added to my runtimes.  Once that was done, both the core CLI and VS publish options worked perfectly.

Comment: This was the solution to my problem.

Comment: One would expect this kind of important thing to work OOB

Answer (score 76):

I received this error after updating VS2015 core template to 1.0.1.  It was because I have a PCL that targets `netstandard 1.4`  if you don't want to have to specify each runtime, Just change the dependency markup for `Microsoft.NETCore.App` to this:

```
"Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
 "type": "platform",
 "version": "1.0.1"
}
```

Comment: The above markup fixed my compile error, but IIS Express wouldn't start after that. Changing "version": "1.0.1" to "version": "1.0.0" solved the IIS issue.

Comment: @Ross update the tools section in project.json to match the version NETCore.App

Comment: In this case  
"tools": {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final"
  },

Comment: @DalSoft - Yes, I updated my VS 2015 a few weeks ago with the latest patches including IISIntegration.Tools, and it solved the Microsoft.NETCore.App: 1.0.1 issue for me.

Comment: @YuriyN. You can update tools using the NuGet package manager. They are just NuGet packages. However, note that you might have to check 'include prerelease' if you are using preview or beta packages.

Comment: What is a PCL??

Comment: @usefulBee Portable Class Library

Comment: This worked for me.  The selected answer caused a whole set of other problems.

Answer (score 35):

in project.json I changed this (added type):

```
//"Microsoft.NETCore.App": "1.1.0",
"Microsoft.NETCore.App": { "version": "1.1.0", "type": "platform" },
```

Now I can build again :-)

**update:** now I can build again but not "run" the website.

You need to make sure you have the runtime and sdk also:

> *) Visual Studio tools include .NET Core 1.0.1. To add .NET Core 1.1 support you need to also install the .NET Core 1.1 runtime.

https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/core#/current

Comment: Looks like you cannot run the website because you need to install [.NET Core 1.1 SDK](https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/core#/current)

Comment: and sometimes reinstalling the Runtime is also needed i found out.

Comment: This helped for me. Thanks! Commenting out "Microsoft.NETCore.App" directly from dependencies in the project.json and changing it to be under "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.1": {
      "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
          "version": "1.1.0",
          "type": "platform"
        }
      }
    }
  },

Comment: Thank you. This 2 simple steps resolved the problem. Hopefully MS will make it more developer friendly in the near future.

Answer (score 20):

I received this error because I used the incredibly broken NuGet Package Manager in Visual Studio 2015 to update my project.json dependencies. It turned this:

```
"frameworks": {
  "netcoreapp1.0": {
    "dependencies": {
      "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
        "type": "platform",
        "version": "1.0.1"
      } 
    }
  }
}
```

into this:

```
"dependencies": {
  "Microsoft.NETCore.App": "1.1.0"
},
"frameworks": {
  "netcoreapp1.0": {}
}
```

Bye bye, platform definition!

Answer (score 15):

If you read these two links:

First, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/tutorials/using-with-xplat-cli

and

second, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/rid-catalog

You will see that you can build a completely portable version using the following snippet in the dependencies root element in project.json.  There is no need to specify runtimes as this is a CORE level runtime which should be platform agnostic, or known as "Framework dependent"

```
"Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
    "type": "platform",
    "version": "1.0.1"
}
```

or you can build for multiple targeted platforms ("self contained applications") by removing the type: platform element like this:

Add this to the dependencies root element in project.json

```
"Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
    "version": "1.0.1"
}
```

and add this as a new root level element

```
"runtimes": {
    "win10-x64": {},  /* one or more RIDs */
    "osx.10.10-x64": {}
  },
```

Multiple targeted requires that you supply platform names known as ".NET Core Runtime IDentifiers (RID)"  A list of these can be found at the second link above.  It includes many flavors of Windows, Linux and OS X.

For a good overview of the various deployment optins, you can read this page as well:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/deploying/index

From the above link:

> You can create two types of deployments for .NET Core applications:
>
> **Framework-dependent deployment**
>
> As the name implies, framework-dependent deployment (FDD) relies on a shared system-wide version of .NET Core to be present on the target system. Because .NET Core is already present, your app is also portable between installations of .NET Core. Your app contains only its own code and any third-party dependencies that are outside of the .NET Core libraries. FDDs contain .dll files that can be launched by using the dotnet utility from the command line. For example, dotnet app.dll runs an application named app.
>
> **Self-contained deployment**
>
> Unlike FDD, a self-contained deployment (SCD) does not rely on any shared components to be present on the target system. All components, including both .NET Core libraries and the .NET Core runtime, are included with the application and are isolated from other .NET Core applications. SCDs include an executable (such as app.exe on Windows platforms for an application named app), which is a renamed version of the platform-specific .NET Core host, and a .dll file (such as app.dll), which is the actual application.

Answer (score 9):

In my case I had just updated all the nuget packages to their latest versions and nuget changed my 'Microsoft.NETCore.App' package reference to the following:

```
"Microsoft.NETCore.App": "1.1.0"
```

I changed it back to the following form and everything worked fine:

```
"Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
      "version": "1.1.0",
      "type": "platform"
    }
```

Good bye 3 hours of my life....

Answer (score 4):

if you execute a dotnet new and look at the output project json, you will see that the monikers have changed.

Make the changes to your project.json as follows:

```
"dependencies": {},
   "frameworks": {
     "netcoreapp1.0": {
        "dependencies": {
         "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
         "type": "platform",
         "version": "1.0.1"
         }
    },
      "imports": "dnxcore50"
    }
  }
```

Comment: For me this is the best solution. .NET Core is in a state of flux and things keep changing. Using the CLI to generate you a project.json to fix changes in your project.json that the NuGet PM can't seem to keep consistent and updated.

Answer (score 0):

I found you need the following in project.json. Here is what was required to fix my error:

**Dependencies**

```
"dependencies": {
   "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
      "version": "1.0.1",
      "type": "platform"
   },
}
```

**Frameworks**

```
"frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "imports": [
        "dotnet5.6",
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
    }
  },
```

**Runtime**

```
  "runtimeOptions": {
    "configProperties": {
      "System.GC.Server": true
    }
  },
```

You might want to add runtimes if you plan on publishing to IIS. Please see something as follows:

```
 "runtimes": {
    "win10-x64": {}
  },
```

Here is a general tip that has worked well for me. When my stuff breaks, I sometimes create a default ASP.NET Core application either the website or empty web api to look at the dependencies in project.json and elsewhere. You can often catch a lot of things that way. The answers above are spot on, but I thought I would write this here in case someone wanted to separate the logic out more in the general template format that ASP.NET Core uses.

Answer (score 0):

In Windows 7 with VS 2015, the soluiton after updating to netcore 1.1.2 was changing the project.json file as following:

```
{
"version": "1.0.0-*",
  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true
  },

  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": "1.1.2"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "imports": "dnxcore50"    //This line must disappear
    }
  },

  "runtimes": {                 //
    "win7-x64": {}              //Add this lines
  }                             //
}
```

After changing this the dependencies will update and viola.

Answer (score -1):

I found one useful link from comment by svick under following page:
https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/2442

Comment: Although your answer is 100% correct, it might also become 100% useless 
if that link is moved, changed, merged into another one or the main site 
just disappears... **:-(** Therefore, please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/41909759/edit) your answer, and copy 
the relevant steps from the link into your answer, thereby guaranteeing 
your answer for 100% of the lifetime of this site! **;-)** You can always 
leave the link in at the bottom of your answer as a source for your 
material...