# getting weird compilation errors - .Net Core

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-core-1.0, project.json

I am not sure what i have done recently. But this was working until a week ago. Suddenly when i tried to compile the project. It is giving me  `8463` compilation errors. few of them are given below.

[image]

Please help me out if any of you have faced this before.  I am using .net core app 1.0.0 . But  1.0.1 is also installed on my PC.

When i try to compile using `dotnet build` cli i get the following error message.

> Can not find runtime target for framework '.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0' compatible with one of the target runtimes: 'win7-x64'. Possible causes:
>
> 1. The project has not been restored or restore failed - run `dotnet restore`
> 2. The project does not list one of 'win7-x64' in the 'runtimes' section.
> 3. You may be trying to publish a library, which is not supported. Use `dotnet pack` to distribute libraries.

I ran `dotnet restore` already. I am not sure about 2nd point. Because it was working before on the same machine.

Also i don't have any `runtimes` section mentioned in the `project.json`

**UPDATE :**

As mentioned in other posts. I added

```
  "runtimes": {
        "win7-x64": { }
      }
```

But didn't work.

Project.Json :

```
{
  "userSecretsId": "aspnet-IdentityServer-db76f1cf-15a8-4dc0-8200-221a224b454c",
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
      "type": "platform",
      "version": "1.0.0"
    },
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Loader": "14.0.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Abstractions": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory": "1.0.0",
    "System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms": "4.2.0",
    "Serilog": "2.2.1",
    "Serilog.Sinks.Literate": "2.0.0",
    "Serilog.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0",
    "IdentityServer4": "1.0.0-beta5",
    "IdentityManager.V2.Entities": "1.0.0-*",
    "IdentityManager.V2.Data": "1.0.0-*",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Google": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Facebook": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Twitter": "1.0.0",
    "Serilog.Sinks.Seq": "3.0.1",
    "System.Runtime": "4.1.0"
  },
  "tools": {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
      "imports": [
        "portable-net45+win8+dnxcore50",
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
    }
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "imports": [
        "dotnet5.6",
        "dnxcore50",
        "portable-net452+win81"
      ]
    }
  },

  "runtimes": {
    "win7-x64": {}
  },

  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true,
    "preserveCompilationContext": true
  },

  "runtimeOptions": {
    "gcServer": true
  },

  "publishOptions": {
    "include": [
      "wwwroot",
      "Views",
      "appsettings.json",
      "web.config"
    ]
  },

  "scripts": {
    "prepublish": [ "npm install", "bower install", "gulp clean", "gulp min" ],
    "postpublish": [ "dotnet publish-iis --publish-folder %publish:OutputPath% --framework %publish:FullTargetFramework%" ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can not find runtime target for framework .NETCoreApp=v1 compatible with one of the target runtimes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37590604/can-not-find-runtime-target-for-framework-netcoreapp-v1-compatible-with-one-of)

Comment: I tried that solution.. But didn't work for me.

Comment: Could you post your project.json?

Comment: It failed for me to restore `IdentityServer4` and `IdentityManager` packages. Bumping up `IdentityServer4` and commenting out  `IdentityManager` packages did the trick.

Comment: Restore is working fine since begining. But when i compile or update any nuget package then getting all the  wierd 8529 compilation errors..

Comment: @Ignas I think identity manager is not for their core product rather for IdSrv 3. I just noticed your old references in project.json when I read your comment on updating the packages... I don't think you need the dnxcore50 call too ...

Answer (score 6):

When we update packages, it will remove   "type": "platform" from
"Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
      "version": "1.1.0",
      "type": "platform"
    }

in Project.json file. after update it looks like  "Microsoft.NETCore.App": "1.1.0" .
Solution of this error is update the Json file with this line e.g

**"Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
      "version": "1.1.0",
      "type": "platform"
    }**