# Can not find runtime target for framework .NETCoreApp=v1 compatible with one of the target runtimes for some projects

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-1.0

I have a solution with many .NET Core projects. I did NuGet updates to all of the project and now when I try to build I get the following errors (for some of the projects - not all):

```
Can not find runtime target for framework '.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0' compatible with one of the target runtimes: 'win10-x64, win81-x64, win8-x64, win7-x64'. Possible causes:
1. The project has not been restored or restore failed - run `dotnet restore`
2. The project does not list one of 'win10-x64, win81-x64, win8-x64, win7-x64' in the 'runtimes' section.
3. You may be trying to publish a library, which is not supported. Use `dotnet pack` to distribute libraries.
```

What seemed to help was a post I found here [Can not find runtime target for framework .NETCoreApp=v1 compatible with one of the target runtimes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37590604/can-not-find-runtime-target-for-framework-netcoreapp-v1-compatible-with-one-of)

I added the following to the failing projects:

```
"runtimes": {
   "win10-x64": { }
}
```

That seemed to fix the issue. But my question is, why was this happening only on some projects? The projects that did not issue the error doesn't have such runtime definition in their `project.json` file.

What exactly does this runtime definition means? how does it affect my ability to run on other os like linux or mac?

Comment: Could you give an example project.json for a project that works and one that doesn't?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> What exactly does this runtime definition means?

`runtimes` lists the runtimes that our package supports. **Listing runtimes is necessary for self-contained deployments**. A deployment is self-contained when it brings its own runtime.

How do we know if our deployment is self-contained? `dependencies` list the packages on which our package depends. These dependencies come in three types.

- `build` the package is for building only and is not part of the deployment
- `platform` the package will depend on a pre-installed runtime
- `default` neither of those

If our `"Microsoft.NETCore.App"` dependency is of the `default` type, then it is self-contained, and we will need to bring our own runtimes. If it is of the `platform` type, then it is framework dependent.

> why was this happening only on some projects?

It will only happen in projects that are self-contained deployments. If you look thru those projects that do not require a `runtimes` property, you will find that they are either class libraries or framework dependent.

## self-contained deployment

```
 "frameworks": {
   "netcoreapp1.0": {
     "dependencies": {
       "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
          "version": "1.0.0"
       }
     }
   }
 },
 "runtimes": {
   "win10-x64": {},
   "osx.10.10-x64": {}
 }
```

## framework dependent deployment

```
 "frameworks": {
   "netcoreapp1.0": {
     "dependencies": {
       "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
          "type": "platform",
          "version": "1.0.0"
       }
     }
   }
 }
```

## class library

```
 "frameworks": {
   "netstandard1.6": {}
 }
```

> how does it affect my ability to run on other os like linux or mac?

It doesn't. Windows, Mac OS, and Linux can all either have a runtime pre-installed or have the application bring its own runtime.

See also

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/tools/project-json
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/deploying/index

  - This link in particular is worth reading to differentiate between self-contained and framework-dependency deployments.
- https://docs.nuget.org/ndocs/schema/project.json

Comment: Thanks for the elaborated answer. So if I understand correctly then with a self-contained deployment I don't need to have the DOTNETCORE installed on linux? Also, as I mentioned, this happened only after I updated NuGet packages - why all of a sudden? does it affect performance?

Comment: I found that if under `"Microsoft.NETCore.App"` instead of leaving it as `"Microsoft.NETCore.App": "1.0.1"` I add `"version": "1.0.1",` and `"type": "platform"` than it compiled without the `runtime` definition. What is this exactly and what is considered better - with or without `runtime` ?

Comment: @developer82 Yes. For a self-contained deployment, you don't need to have the DOTNETCORE installed on Linux.

Comment: @developer82 Why all of a sudden? To answer that, I would need to see the Nuget packages before and after your update.

Comment: @developer82 Does it affect performance? As far as I know, it does not affect performance. In one case, the runtime is already installed on the machine; in the other case, your app restores the runtime from NuGet. So long as it's the same runtime, it will not affect performance, as far as I know.

Comment: @developer82 When you use `"type" : "platform"`, you are creating a framework-dependent deployment. When you omit `"type": "platform"`, you are creating a self-contained deployment. Neither is considered better; rather, each has its own use case.