# .net Core API ERRORS

Tags: c#, mongodb, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have recently update my nuget packages and now I am receiving these four errors. I have no Idea where to begin or where to start debugging this issue. Here are the errors...

[image]

I am confused as to where the 'runtime section' is located. I would be happy to share code it is posted on my git [here](https://github.com/bcrawford11/MongoAPI). Thank you for any of your time and help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your `project.json` file defines what frameworks you are saying that your app targets.  If you're set on targetting net core (which you don't *have* to do in an asp.net core application), you can add the runtimes section:

```
"runtimes": {
    "win7-64": {}
}
```

like it says.

Or you can choose to target a different framework.  For example, if you want to target simply .NET 4.6.2, you can change the frameworks section to:

```
"frameworks": {
    "net462": {}
},
```

[The docs page](http://docs.nuget.org/ndocs/schema/target-frameworks) can help clear up all the different frameworks you can target.

Comment: I am using a .net core application so why am I having to add the runtimes section? I am confused.... you are saying I don't have to add it, but I am getting this error so I do?

Comment: there's a good answer on that [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40191498/can-not-find-runtime-target-for-framework-netcoreapp-v1-compatible-with-one-of)