# How to compile .NET Core app for Linux on a Windows machine

Tags: c#, linux, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm developing a .NET Core app on a Windows 10 machine (with Visual Studio 2015 update 3 + Microsoft .NET Core 1.0.1 VS 2015 Tooling Preview 2) which should published on an Ubuntu 16 machine. To do that, I have to move my source code to the end machine and compile it there, to get it to run. e.g. I'm not able to compile the code on windows and run it on linux. Question: Is there any way to compile the code on win machine and run it on linux?

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Using [dotnet build](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/tools/dotnet-build) command, you may specify `--runtime` flag

> -r|--runtime < RUNTIME_IDENTIFIER >
>
> Target runtime to build for. For a list of Runtime Identifiers (RIDs) you can use, see the [RID catalog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/rid-catalog).

RIDs that represent concrete operating systems usually follow this pattern `[os].[version]-[arch]`

Fo example, to build a project and its dependencies for Ubuntu 16.04 runtime use:

```
dotnet build --runtime ubuntu.16.04-x64
```

Comment: Thanks. But i'm getting this error: `Can not find runtime target for framework '.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0' compatible with one of the target runtimes: 'win10-x64, win81-x64, win8-x64, win7-x64'.`

Comment: @Javad_Amiry you need to specify that you project support those runtimes. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/37590605/2833802 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/40194003/2833802 SO answers

Comment: Just to add a more recent update to this answer. You would need to set the RuntimeIdentifier in the csproj file with what ever runtimes you would target, i.e: <RuntimeIdentifiers>win10-x64;ubuntu.16.04-x64</RuntimeIdentifiers>

Comment: When should this runtime flag be used? Is it a general flag which applies to all use cases just to optimize the generated binaries for specific platform? Specifically, is it only used to build self-contained binaries or it can also be used to build app which runs on dotnet core SDK/Runtime?

Answer (score 12):

```
dotnet publish **path to your solution** --configuration Release --framework netcoreapp3.0 --output .**output path** --self-contained false --runtime linux-x64 --verbosity quiet
```

Comment: is this the same as right click on project, publish => set framework to Linux and publish it?

Answer (score 12):

For anyone who's now seeing this not working anymore, it seems as of the update on the 10th of November 2020 you have to specify the project file now as it doesn't like using a specified runtime on a solution (.sln) anymore.

An issue about this was raised here (https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/14281) but obviously that's not going to get resolved immediately.

So previously where this would work:

```
dotnet build --runtime ubuntu.xx.xx-x64
```

It wants something like this now:

```
dotnet build ProjectName.csproj --runtime ubuntu.xx.xx-x64
```

Answer (score 12):

### Option 1: Command line

```
dotnet build ProjectFile.csproj --runtime linux-x64
```

Works on Linux and Windows and Mac.

### Option 2: Visual Studio

You can also "publish" your app in Visual Studio if you prefer. Choose "File System" publish method and set this setting:

[image]

Comment: @E_Blue For both.

Comment: Only works with C# code, not Basic code, right?

Answer (score 0):

2024, you can directly copy the files to your linux host:

```
myapp.dll
myapp.runtimeconfig.json
```

note: `myapp.exe` is not needed

then to run the app

```
dotnet myapp.dll
```