# Dotnet core 2.1 code build for Linux from Windows machine

Tags: .net-core

I am creating a dotnet core 2.1 mvc application. I use win 10 as development machine but my prod server is Linux. Is it OK to Build it on Windows machine Or should I use a Linux box to build and then deploy on prod? Any execution or references or performance issues I might face?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot build on Windows and deploy the same on to Linux.

For eg: dotnet build --runtime ubuntu.16.04-x64

Look into the [following](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41533592/how-to-compile-net-core-app-for-linux-on-a-windows-machine) on how to build specific to linux