# How do you compile and run .NET Core Services for Linux?

Tags: c#, linux, ubuntu, .net-core, systemd

I'm trying to develop a C# Worker Service with .NET Core 3.1 and run it as a service on an Ubuntu machine.

I found [this guide](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/net-core-and-systemd/?WT.mc_id=-blog-scottha) to set up Worker Services on Linux, but I'm getting errors (see screenshot) when trying to start the service.

The guide does not specify how to compile the solution for Linux, so I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41533592/how-to-compile-net-core-app-for-linux-on-a-windows-machine) and compiled a package using `dotnet build --runtime ubuntu.18.04-x64`. The result is a folder with my Application and no file extension, as well as a long list of .dll files.

Is this the correct way of publishing Worker Services, or generally .NET Core Applications targeting Linux, on a Windows machine? I wasn't able to find any official documentation or other resources on how to properly do this.

I unfortunately can't directly develop on the Ubuntu machine, as it only has a command-line interface.

[image]

Comment: Publish as self contained, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/#publish-self-contained Then you won't need anything else on the target Ubuntu machine. Also never post something like "I'm getting errors" here in the future. We expect you describe the actual errors in details.

Comment: @LexLi Is -runtime and -r the same parameter? If so, I already did that. Sorry for not specifying the error, I added a screenshot of the error message I am getting.

Comment: Learn the Linux command `chmod` please.

Comment: @LexLi I used it to set the files to 777, but it didn't change anything.

Comment: Then your debugging on .NET Core side is finished. Try more general Linux side debugging https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/472950/systemd-status-203-exec-error-when-creating-new-service

Comment: @JohannesMols did you find a working solution ?

Comment: @Vinod no, unfortunately not

Comment: @JohannesMols , it worked for me after giving the 777 permission for published files which your going to host. (.dll,config & json)

Comment: Following [this](https://medium.com/bluekiri/packaging-a-net-core-service-for-ubuntu-4f8e9202d1e5) article did it for me.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the documentation for `dotnet run` `ubuntu.18.04-x64` looks like an incorrect runtime:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/rid-catalog

> Only common values are listed. For the latest and complete version, see the runtime.json file on the dotnet/runtime repository. Devices running a distribution not listed below may work with one of the Portable RIDs. For example, Raspberry Pi devices running a Linux distribution not listed can be targeted with linux-arm.

- Portable (.NET Core 2.0 or later versions)

  - linux-x64 (Most desktop distributions like CentOS, Debian, Fedora, Ubuntu, and derivatives)
  - linux-musl-x64 (Lightweight distributions using musl like Alpine Linux)
  - linux-arm (Linux distributions running on ARM like Raspberry Pi)
- Red Hat Enterprise Linux

  - rhel-x64 (Superseded by linux-x64 for RHEL above version 6)
  - rhel.6-x64 (.NET Core 2.0 or later versions)
- Tizen (.NET Core 2.0 or later versions)

  - tizen
  - tizen.4.0.0
  - tizen.5.0.0

so instead of `dotnet build --runtime ubuntu.18.04-x64` try `dotnet build --runtime linux-x64`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. That unfortunately doesn't change anything, I'm still getting the same errors. I will update my question with the error message in a second.

Comment: Might be a good idea to post some of your code as the error message seems related to what your doing code wise

Comment: I updated the screenshot as I tried a fix to my actual error messages and forgot to change it back. It's saying Permission Denied, even though I am running the command with sudo and I set file without a file extension to be executable. The code itself is extremely basic and basically only prints out a test message.

Comment: Hey sorry about the late reply but it looks like this is a file/folder persmision thing, have you tried running this under the super user? i.e. `sudo dotnet build --runtime linux-x64`, you may wan to check your users persmissions to those files and folders

Answer (score 1):

Following [this](https://medium.com/bluekiri/packaging-a-net-core-service-for-ubuntu-4f8e9202d1e5) article did it for me.

The article's example uses "linux-x64" as the [dotnet publish runtime identifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/rid-catalog), that's what I used (my machine also runs Ubuntu). Until proved the contrary, seems like "linux-x64" may run properly in different distributions.

Am leaving here one question I posted on a related issue I faced during the process of deploying my .net core worker service as a systemd daemon/service unit in linux.

- [control the output directory where dotnet single file publish extracts to](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/615635/433212)