# How to Compile a C# Project for Use on Linux?

Tags: c#

I downloaded a C# project from github and compiled it with Visual Studio using the `dotnet build` command and apparently everything went well. But I can't use it on Centos, not even using Mono . Which command should I use to compile a C# project in VisualStudio for use on Linux? I used `dotnet build` which generated me a project with .exe file and I tried to run it with Mono and I got this error `File does not contain a valid CIL image.`

sorry if this is the wrong area to ask

Comment: Which runtime are you targeting?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to compile .NET Core app for Linux on a Windows machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41533592/how-to-compile-net-core-app-for-linux-on-a-windows-machine)

Comment: i use SDK .NET 6, but I'm new to this, how do I see this?

Comment: Open your .csproj file, there will be an XML element near the top that says "TargetFramework"

Comment: <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are different ways to do it and they depend on what you're trying to achieve.

From [.NET application publishing overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/)

> | Type | Command |
> | --- | --- |
> | framework-dependent executable for the current platform. | dotnet publish |
> | framework-dependent executable for a specific platform. | dotnet publish -r --self-contained false |
> | framework-dependent cross-platform binary. | dotnet publish |
> | self-contained executable. | dotnet publish -r |

From the Examples section:

> Publish an app cross-platform framework-dependent. A Linux 64-bit executable is created along with the dll file. This command doesn't work with .NET Core SDK 2.1.
>
> ```
> dotnet publish -r linux-x64 --self-contained false
> ```

---

You may be interested in [Single-file deployment and executable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/single-file/overview?tabs=cli):

> Bundling all application-dependent files into a single binary provides an application developer with the attractive option to deploy and distribute the application as a single file. Single-file deployment is available for both the [framework-dependent deployment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/#publish-framework-dependent) model and [self-contained applications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/#publish-self-contained).