# Unknown error when publishing standalone WPF Net core 5 application from Visual Studio 2019 for linux x64

Tags: linux, wpf, visual-studio-2019, publish, .net-5

I'm trying to create a WPF Net Core 5 app from Visual Studio Community 2019 on Windows and publish it with standalone deployment mode (runtime included) for use on linux X64 without having to install the runtime on the target. When publishing, Visual Studio shows an error. Reviewing the log, "The source of the problem could not be determined."
If I select "Framework Dependent" deployment mode it works correctly.
What can be the error?

Thanks.

If I select "Framework Dependent" deployment mode, it works correctly. But I try to avoid installing the runtime on the destination.

Comment: As far as I know, you **cannot** run a WPF Core App on Linux.

Answer (score 1):

WPF is a Windows-only technology, it won't run on Linux. Some cross-platform alternatives that are similar enough are MAUI and Avalonia.

Comment: So what is the use of the option to publish with target execution environment "linux-X64" ?     https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41533592/how-to-compile-net-core-app-for-linux-on-a-windows-machine  See the image on Alex message.

Comment: @Raúl Simply the VS developers forgot to disable that for whatever reasons. But since WPF is never supported on Linux by Microsoft, the error you met is the ultimate red flag to stop you from going that path.