# Trouble building self contained .NetCore App

Tags: c#, command-line-interface, .net-core, self-contained

So I am trying to build a self contained .NetCore App, just a simple default hello world one.

I followed [Scott Hanselman's](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/SelfcontainedNETCoreApplications.aspx) example on how to create the app after googling for answers.

So I have this code in my project.json

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "buildOptions": {
    "debugType": "portable",
    "emitEntryPoint": true
  },
  "dependencies": {},
  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.1": {
      "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
          //"type": "platform",
          "version": "1.1.0"
        }
      },
      "imports": "dnxcore50",
      "runtimes": {
        "win10-x64": {},
        "osx.10.10-x64": {},
        "ubuntu.14.04-x64": {}
      }
    }
  }
}
```

As you can see I have commented out the type line and added the runtimes for each platform.

But I keep getting this error:

```
Can not find runtime target for framework '.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.1' compatible with one of the targe
t runtimes: 'osx.10.10-x64'. Possible causes:
1. The project has not been restored or restore failed - run `dotnet restore`
2. The project does not list one of 'osx.10.10-x64' in the 'runtimes' section.
3. You may be trying to publish a library, which is not supported. Use `dotnet pack` to distribute li
braries.
```

Now I am running this on a Mac, but the same error happens on ubuntu but then reports error relating it to ubuntu.

My dotNet version is = 1.0.0-preview2-1-003177

I am a bit stuck, everything seems to point to the fact it should work and it is probably an obvious thing I am overlooking.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need change the structure of your json to:

```
{
    "version": "1.0.0-*",
    "buildOptions": {
        "debugType": "portable",
        "emitEntryPoint": true
    },
    "dependencies": {},
    "frameworks": {
        "netcoreapp1.1": {
            "dependencies": {
                "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
                    "version": "1.1.0"
                }
             }
         }
    },
    "runtimes": {
        "win10-x64": {},
        "osx.10.10-x64": {},
        "ubuntu.14.04-x64": {}
    }
}
```

Big difference is that the `runtimes` section is **not within** the `framework` section.

Be sure to run a `dotnet restore --no-cache` after you changed your project.json.

You can find more information on Self contained deployment (SCD) on this [page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/deploying/index#self-contained-deployments-scd) and with this excellent [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40191498/can-not-find-runtime-target-for-framework-netcoreapp-v1-compatible-with-one-of)