# Database first migration EF Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I am trying to migrate the NORTWIND database to a test project with EF Core. I have with the help of the web overcome sevrel obstaclesbut but as of right now I am stuck. So I would be very pleased if someone out there could shed some light on my problem. Perhaps point me in the right direction.

Problem:
When I run:

Scaffold-DbContext "Data Source=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=NORTHWND;Integrated Security=True;" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Models

in the Package Manager Console in VS I get the message Build Error. I cant pinpoint the problem so I have a hard time searching for a solutions on the web.

This is my project.Json:

```
 "dependencies": {
"Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Loader": "14.0.0",
"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer": "1.1.0",
"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design": "1.1.0",
"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Design": "1.1.0",
"BundlerMinifier.Core": "2.2.306",
"Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore": "1.0.2",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics": "1.1.0",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.1.0",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": "1.1.0-preview4-final",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing": "1.1.0",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.1.0",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": "1.1.0-preview4-final",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.1.0",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.1.0",
"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.1.0-preview4-final",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.1.0",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.1.0",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.1.0",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.1.0",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.1.0",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions": "1.1.0"
  },

 "tools": {
"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.1.0-preview4-final"
  },
```

This is the error I get:

[image]

This is the Error code:

[image]

Tell me if there is something else you want to se from my project. I know it can perhaps be hard to give help from the information I have provided. But I will gladly post more info. Just tell me what you want to see.

Thanks for all the help and hints!

Comment: What error you get?

Comment: Try building the project from VS first (not from the package manager console), it may give you more details about the build error.

Comment: Your project is failing to build, you can't run the scaffolder until the project builds. It's got nothing to do with the EF or the scaffolding command. In the top menu, click 'View' > 'Error List' to see the errors stopping it building.

Comment: I updated the initial post with a eror list picture.

Comment: Try to change `netcoreapp1.0` to `netcoreapp1.1` in your project.json  and you should be fine.

Comment: unfortunatelydidnt do the trick. :(

Comment: @AllramEst In addintion add `"runtimes": {"win10-x64": { } }` to your project.json also  [check this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37590604/can-not-find-runtime-target-for-framework-netcoreapp-v1-compatible-with-one-of) it might be related.

Comment: Thanks! I´ll check this solution as soon as I can

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello and Thanks to everybody for all the help. Finally imported a database. The things that did it was to Update the solution thru the NuGet package manager for the solution and adding these line to the dependencies:

> ```
> "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
>       "version": "1.1.0",
>       "type": "platform"
>     },
>
>    "runtimes": { "win10-x64": {} },
> ```

Once again Thanks to all for your suggestions!!!!
How do you place the chechmark on multiple answers? Becasue everybodys answers finally made me solve the problem.

Comment: You can up vote the answers and comments that were helpful but check only one answer that was most complete and answering most correctly the question.

Answer (score 1):

The link below shows the step-by-step procedure. I had some problems with VS 2017 RC resolved by updating all packages with the -pre option and installing dotnet core 1.1 on the PC.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/aspnetcore/existing-db

;-)

Comment: Restarted with a new project and followed the tutorial in the link you shared. Still Build Error..

Comment: sorry, you've tried this on the PMC (I assume that your choise is Web Application with Individual Users Authentication) : 
Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet -pre
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools  -pre
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools -pre

Comment: Also try to update your sdk core:
https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/core#/current

Comment: Sorry. Updated the SDK and all the packages but no luck

Comment: I tried in VS 2017 RC and works... I'm sorry... But if I can give a advice, you should try to download it becouse, if you dev dotnet core, the project env. is changed again. You don't have a project.json but a csproj configuration file, bower and more stuff. I have abandoned VS2015 to VS2017... good luck Luca

Comment: I am downloading VS 2017 RC now I´ll give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

You look to be missing references for:

```
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational 
Micorsoft.EntityFrameWorkCore.Relational.Design
```

You may also need:

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Server.Abstractions
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions
```

Comment: If your server is part of a domain your connection string will need to change to be something like: `Server=(localdb)\\domain\\mssqllocaldb;Data Source=xxxxxxx;Initial Catalog=NorthwindDb;Trusted_Connection=True;`